# sql update query for multiple results. (without inner joins & triggers)

Tags: sql, nested

```
UPDATE invoice 
SET totalAmount = ( SELECT SUM(price) AS 'total' 
                    FROM cart c , cartitem ci , item i 
                    WHERE c.cartId = ci.cartId AND ci.itemId = i.itemId 
                    AND c.cartId = 1
                )
WHERE cartId =1;

UPDATE invoice 
SET totalAmount = ( SELECT SUM(price) AS 'total' 
                    FROM cart c , cartitem ci , item i 
                    WHERE c.cartId = ci.cartId AND ci.itemId = i.itemId 
                    AND c.cartId = 2
                )
WHERE cartId =2;
```

please refer the SQL code. Instead of updating record by record is there any solution to update all record at once. By the way this is  for an assignment I can't use inner joins or triggers for this.
Thank you.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

Make the subquery correlated to the update (c.cartId = invoice.cartId) and you will be able to update as many invoices as you need in a single statement.

```
UPDATE invoice 
SET totalAmount = ( SELECT SUM(price) AS 'total' 
                    FROM cart c , cartitem ci , item i 
                    WHERE c.cartId = ci.cartId AND ci.itemId = i.itemId 
                    AND c.cartId = invoice.cartId
                )
WHERE cartId in (1, 2);
```

Comment: won't you need inner  filter to restrict `sum`

Comment: No, having c.cartId = invoice.cartId on the filter it would only sum the items of your invoice.

Comment: there is no correlation,so the subquery will be invoked once for all rows

Comment: Thank you . this is not what I expected. but this gave me the idea how to do it.

Comment: The last part of the filter is the correlation, c.cartId = invoice.cartId, it depends of the invoice so it will be called for every row to update (invoice table).

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE invoice i
SET totalAmount = 
    ( SELECT SUM(price) AS 'total' 
        FROM cart c , cartitem ci , item i 
        WHERE c.cartId = ci.cartId AND ci.itemId = i.itemId 
        AND c.cartId = i.cartId
    )
WHERE cartId IN (1, 2);
```

if you refer to `cartId` as field in `invoice` table

Comment: won't you need inner  filter to restrict `sum`

Answer (score 1):

Try This it should work for you:

```
UPDATE i SET i.totalAmount = t.total
FROM invoice i
INNER JOIN ( SELECT c.cartId, SUM(price) AS total
                FROM cart c , cartitem ci , item i 
                WHERE c.cartId = ci.cartId AND ci.itemId = i.itemId 
                AND c.cartId IN (1,2)
         GROUP BY c.cartId
) t ON t.cartId = i.cartId
```

Comment: This is going to assign the same value to the invoice 1 and  2 : the sum of their items combined, which is not what the queries on the question do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create scalar function for sub query and use that for update totalAmount.
as

```
 --Select dbo.fnGetTotalCartAmount(1)
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetTotalCartAmount](@cartId int )
RETURNS numeric(18,2)
AS       
BEGIN
  declare @TotalAmount numeric(18,2)
                 SELECT @TotalAmount = SUM(price)
                    FROM cart c , cartitem ci , item i 
                    WHERE c.cartId = ci.cartId AND ci.itemId = i.itemId 
                    AND c.cartId = @cartId

 RETURN @TotalAmount;

END
```

and use in you update statement like below.

```
UPDATE invoice  SET totalAmount = dbo.fnGetTotalCartAmount(cartId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE invoice 
SET totalAmount = ( SELECT SUM(price) AS 'total' 
                    FROM cart c  join cartitem ci 
                    on c.cartId = ci.cartId join item i on  ci.itemId = i.itemId 
                    AND c.cartId  in (1,2)
                )
WHERE cartId  in (1,2)
```

Comment: This is going to assign the same value to the invoice 1 and  2 : the sum of their items combined, which is not what the queries on the question do.